# Nginx serve one, specific PHP script for all .HTML requests

Tags: nginx, php-fpm

**In short, I need to run a specific php file, `patch.php`, every time someone requests an html page on this site...**

We recently moved from an Apache server to an Nginx server, and everything has been great. 
However, this one site that looks like it was coded ages ago has a very peculiar schema:

*All the links on all of the pages link to .html files, but the html files are missing the header and the footer*

I'm not sure how this site worked before, but the way I see to fix it is to simply tell nginx that any time someone requests an html file, simply serve them a php file that will include the header, the page they want, and the footer.

But my attempts so far have not been successful. From [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8644783/html-files-as-php-in-nginx) question, I made the following:

```
    location ~\.(htm|html)$ {
            root /home/www-dev/domain.com/web;
            fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
            fastcgi_index patch.php; #the patch file I want to run for all html
            include fastcgi_params;
    }
```

Which was much better than my first couple of attempts, but, it does not work -- 
Oddly enough, it tells me "Access Denied" - which is not what the usual error page looks like, but the ownership and permissions are correct, so I don't think that is related.

So, I would really like to know what I'm doing wrong --- thanks in advance - !

Comment: What was the original Apache configuration for the server?

Comment: I have no idea. I could not find an .htaccess file, but I guess the next step is to look harder.

Comment: `I'm not sure how this site worked before` - probably by using [auto_prepend_file](http://docs.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.auto-prepend-file) and  [auto_append_file](http://docs.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.auto-append-file). If you look at the php fpm logs most likely it's telling you that files don't exist - because SCRIPT_NAME SCRIPT_FILENAME are going to be set from the request.

Comment: Hmmm. But wouldn't that only append to `*.php` files?

Comment: Showing the apache config would clarify. That means the files in `/etc/apache/...`. Also, you should show your _whole_ nginx config (the server block). not just the one location block that's currently in the question.

Comment: You are including `root` directive in your `location` block, which is not a good idea. `root` should be only used in `server` blocks. If you want to serve files from some other directory on server for some particular URIs, then you use `alias` directive inside the `location` for those files.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can redirect all request to a single php file/url:

1. setup nginx to serve your patch.php (somthing like):

`location /patch\.php {
  fastcgi_pass unix:/path/to/your/php-fastcgi.socket;
  fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME /path/to/your/file/patch.php;
}`

2. redirect all requests to your patch.php

`rewrite ^(.*)$ /patch.php break;`

Comment: Can you explain what the `break` would do ? -- I'm not sure how that would impact our SEO efforts...

Comment: let's have a look at the nginx docs (@ http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_rewrite_module.html)

break => Stops processing the current set of ngx_http_rewrite_module directives.

Comment: `rewrite ^(.*)$` - that'll make it impossible to serve any static files - such as `/favicon.ico`

Comment: I'm sorry, I read the docs, but I don't understand it; it doesn't talk about how that is different from `permanent` which is the only other one I know.

Comment: Well, if that rewrites the URL, then we'll have SEO issues--- I think... don't really want `patch.php` showing up in Google...

Comment: If it issued a redirect no html file would be accessible as they'd all point at the same url `/patch.php` - I recommend a) reading the documentation b) reading it again c) trying things on a local/test install and not guessing what things do, but seeing for yourself.

Comment: Lol, that too - ! - but it would be easy enough to save the REQUEST_URI into a Session variable - I've played around with this, before - we had an issue with 404s on images, but I was able to tell nginx to serve a generic image for those - ! I was hoping for something similar, here, but it just doesn't seem to work properly.

Comment: `it would be easy enough to save the REQUEST_URI into a Session variable` - Above you say you understand the rewrite to be a redirect which if it were true REQUEST_URI would be `/patch.php` - there's a lot of assumption and guess work going on instead of editing the question to add the information that would make it answerable.

Answer (score 3):

One possible solution to your problem.

This solution assumes that your patch.php is in `/home/www-dev/nasa.gov/web/patch.php` file.

```
server {
    server_name your.domain.name;
    root /home/www-dev/nasa.gov/web;

    rewrite \.(htm|html)$ /patch.php break;

    location /patch.php$ {
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
        include fastcgi_params;
    }
}
```

The first location block matches all files ending with htm/html suffix, and makes an internal rewrite to pass them all to /patch.php. This has nothing to do with HTTP redirects that are sent when using `permanent` (301) or `redirect` (302) modifier, so this has no effect on SEO.

The second location tells to process `/patch.php` via the PHP instance. If you want to enable general processing of PHP scripts, you should use this instead:

```
location ~ \.php$ {
    fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
    fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
    fastcgi_index index.php;
    include fastcgi_params;
}
```

Comment: Good point, the location block is not needed here. I'll edit the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Change the configuration of your webserver in a way that `.html` files are parsed as PHP. I won't go into details on how to do that, there are plenty of guides out there already.

Then, change your `php.ini` and add [`auto-prepend-file`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.auto-prepend-file) and [`auto-append-file`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.auto-append-file).

Comment: It's also possible to add this to the nginx config: `fastcgi_param PHP_VALUE "auto_prepend_file=/path/to/php/file.php";`